# multiprocessing pool: showing number of ready unprocessed results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using python's `multiprocessing.Pool` and `imap_unordered` I'm queuing a long list of slowish tasks to a set of workers in a pool. Iterating over the result object, I'm able to handle results as they are ready regardless of their submission order, where I execute an additional chunk of logic that cannot be parallelized and included in `imap_unordered`'s `func`.

I would like to be able to list how many tasks are already "complete" (aka `func` executed and returned) and are ready, but have not yet been iterated over.

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
def exp_func(i):
    time.sleep(i)
    print("func", i)

def fun_unparallelable(i):
    print("fun_unparallelable", i)
    time.sleep(10)

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
result_iter = p.imap_unordered(exp_func, range(1000))

done = 0
for result in result_iter:
    done += 1
    print("done", done)
    print("ready", get_pool_ready(...))
    fun_unparallelable(i)
```

Since `fun_unparallelable` takes a constant time it is expected to be insignificant in the grand scheme of things, but at peak times or after a long set of relatively fast `exp_func` calls (as so happens in the initial executions of `exp_func`) there's an expected backlog of tasks for which `exp_func` has finished executing but have not been iterated yet.

To make this as clear as possible, here's the expected output at given times since execution:

I would expect to have the following output at `t == 1`:

```
func 1
done 1
ready 0
```

and then at `t == 9`, the additional output:

```
func 2
func 3
func 4
func 5
func 6
func 7
func 8
func 9
```

And finally at `t == 11`, the following will be additionally printed:

```
func 10
done 2
ready 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no public interface to the information you're interested in.

In your case, `imap_unordered` will return a `IMapUnorderedIterator` but this return type is not guaranteed.  In some cases, a generator is returned instead (and the documentation promises nothing beyond an iterator).

In the case where `IMapUnorderedIterator` is returned, a private attribute `_items` holds all elements that are available but haven't yet been iterated over.  So, accessing this private attribute, you can inspect `len(result_iter._items)` to find the information you want (obviously it is only correct at most at the instant of inspection since the pool may add new results at any time, but presumably that's still useful to you).

You may want to consider contributing a patch to the multiprocessing library which exposes this information under a public interface.

Comment: Thanks! How would one begin the journey of contributing code to the multiprocessing library?

Comment: File an issue on bugs.python.org describing what you want and why, post to python-dev pointing at the issue to attempt to gather interest, take a look at https://devguide.python.org/ if you don't get any feedback that says it's a change that can't ever possibly be accepted.